# React Navigation Stack with Tab Navigator using keyboard destroy the main screen for IOS (android works good)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a simple stack navigator with two screens, the main one, and another one with simple text input component.
When i entered the screen and directly go back doing nothing with the back button, everything is just fine, but if i click on the text input and open the keyboard, then go back, my main screen have weird and unexplained left margin. I have Tab Navigator too, when i use the stack navigator as the appcontainer it works fine, but when i use the stack navigator in the tab navigator its happen, probably the tab navigator causes the problem but how can i fix it? see pictures:
Important to mention that is works great on android, the problem is only for IOS!

Main Screen at the beginning:
[image]

Nested screen with text input:
[image]

Main screen after i opened keyboard and then backed:
[image]

Please please please help out guys

Comment: Hi @user1831541, I am also facing the same issue. I came across this question when trying resolve above mentioned issue. This issue came when i updated expo SDK to 36. Did you resolve this by any chance? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved this issue by changing "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12" to "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.22" in package.json

Also updated below imports in App.js
-import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";
+import { useScreens } from "react-native-screens";
```